# Get a Bound Object from a control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have the following xaml:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Name}"></Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In my code I have an event that gives me access to the button.  How can I take the button object and get the object that it's Name is bound to?

Here is psudo code that I would like to work:

```
public void MyEvent(Object obj)
{
   Button myButton = (Button) obj;
   MyBoundClass myObject = GetBoundClassFromProperty(myButton.Name);

   // Do something with myObject.
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try accessing the DataContext property. This will contain a reference to the current item the button is bound to.

```
public void MyEvent(Object obj) 
{ 
   Button myButton = (Button) obj; 
   MyBoundClass myObject = myButton.DataContext as MyBoundClass;

   // Do something with myObject. 
}
```

Comment: Sweet!  So simple but so right!  Best kind of answer.  Thanks